# How to remove module layer in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I have three modules: module-a, module-b, module-c. Module-a and module-b are in boot layer. Layer for module-c I create myself. Module-c has JPMS implementation of the service which interface is in module-a.

This is the way I create layer with module-c in module-b.

```
ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(moduleCPath);
ModuleLayer parent = ModuleLayer.boot();
Configuration cf = parent.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of("module-c"));
ClassLoader scl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ModuleLayer layer = parent.defineModulesWithOneLoader(cf, scl);
```

Then in module-b I call service from module-c. After service execution completed I don't need module-c and new created layer any more. How to remove it from JVM and release all resources? Is it enough to do `layer = null;`?

Comment: Does creating a new `ModuleLayer` without `module-c` not work?

Comment: Could you update the question with what exactly you tried and what did it result in please.

Comment: @nullpointer My question has all the information, what I do and what is the question about. If you don't understand something, please say what you don't understand.

Comment: Could you include in the question what are you trying to achieve by removing the module, like what is it that the `layer` after that be used for. Or would it not be used even?

Comment: @nullpointer Yes, you are right. `layer` will not be used anymore. What I want to do is to remove this `layer` from memory and release all resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module layer, the modules in the layer, and class loaders supporting the layer, are eligible to be GC'ed/unloaded when they are no longer reachable.

If you want to prove this to yourself then create a weak reference to the `layer` object and you should see that the reference is cleared (and queued if you are using a reference queue) when the layer is GC'ed.

Comment: What happened if singleton object (from module) loaded to ram , then remove module ? singleton removed immediately ?

Answer (score 1):

An [`EMPTY_LAYER`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#empty--) shall solve your use-case(from one of the comments on the question, trying to assign `new HashSet<>` as roots) here, wherein the references to other layers no more handled within the `layer` that you created :

```
layer = ModuleLayer.empty();
```

> Returns the empty layer. There are no modules in the empty layer. It
>   has no parents.

---

On the thought of being able to remove a layer explicitly form the JVM, I would not probably expect such an API exposed publicly since a JVM is supposed to have at least one non-empty layer, the ***boot layer***, that is created when the Java virtual machine is started.

And if such a method is exposed, I wonder if users can try and remove this layer as well. Though I am trying to be technically hypothetical on this part.